# XSLT for-each iteration (problems with attributes on ancestors)

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I got a simple problem, in my XML file I have parameters on my ancestors nodes, and when I try to iterate then, from my xslt file it doesn't work.

As example, my XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <nfeProc versao="3.10" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
        <NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
            <infNFe Id="NFe99999" versao="3.10">
                <ide>
                    <cUF>35</cUF>
                    ...
                </ide>
                <emit>
                    <CNPJ>01881662000180</CNPJ>
                    ...
                </emit>
              </infNFe>
           </NFe>
     </NFeProc>
```

And my XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CNPJs/h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Number</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="nfeProc/NFe/infNFe/emit">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="./CNPJ" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run this example, I don't get anything as a result.

On my tests, i discover that the problem (I guess) is related to the parameters inside the ancestors tag. If i remove the attribute xmlns tag, from both nfeProc and NFe tags, i get the result as expected (my CNPJ value)

```
xmlns="http:/www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"
```

Somebody knows how to handle this problem? what are the problem exatcly and how to solve it?

Because I can't change the XML structure, as it comes from government.

**Edit**

As answered by the fellows, the problems is related to namespaces. I'll continue searching, and already made some changes, putting the namespaces in my XSLT file as follow:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:t="http:/www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
```

and changing my for each to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="t:nfeProc/t:NFe/infNFe/emit">
```

But continue not working, i doesn't return any erros, but don't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Classic problem of default namespaces. Search the term and try for a solution.

Comment: You're right, as I was without direction i didn't know what search. I was thinking that xmlns was just simple parameter from the tag. I'll take a look at.

Comment: You have missed a `/` from the namespace. It should be `http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe` and not `http:/www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe`. Also, you need to use the `t:` prefix in front of all elements in the xpath `t:nfeProc/t:NFe/t:infNFe/t:emit`, as the default namespace is inherited (i.e. You don't need `xmlns="..."` on all elements in your XML, not unless the namespace is different for children)

Comment: Thanks, Tim C! you're right! everything is working now (or, at least, this part of the job... haha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove all `xmlns-namespace` yes.

Or you can use it in xPath for all herited nodes :

```
t:nfeProc/t:NFe/t:infNFe/t:emit
```

With the declaration :

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:t="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
```

Comment: Thanks! but it don't seems to work for me. Searching I know now that your answer makes sense for what I posted! Thanks so, I'll continue trying.

Comment: What I missed is that every element in the xPath needed the t: prefix, as mentioned by @Tim C in comments above. Thanks, is working now. :)